# Make class pointer point to address containing it's members

Tags: c++

I have following class:

```
typedef class object_struct
{
public:
    u16    graph_node_type;        /* 0x00 */
    u16    graph_flags;
    struct object_struct *prev;                  /* previous linked list object */
    struct object_struct *next;                  /* next linked list object */ 
    u32    graph_parent;
    u32    graph_child;            /* 0x10 */
    u32    geo_layout_ptr;         /* 0x14 */
    u32    _0x18;
    u32    _0x1c;
    float  _0x20;             /* 0x20 */
    float  _0x24;
    float  _0x28;
    float  x_scaling;              /* 0x2c */
    float  y_scaling;              /* 0x30 */
    float  z_scaling;
    u16    _0x38;
    u16    _0x3a;
    u32    animation;              /* 0x3c - current animation */
    u16    anim_current_frame;     /* 0x40 */
    u16    anim_timer;             /* timer, animation related? */
    u16    anim_current_frame_copy;
    u16    _0x46;
    u32    _0x48;
    u32    _0x4c;
    u32    matrix_ptr;             /* 0x50 */
    float  float_0x54;
    float  float_0x58;
    float  float_0x5c;
    struct object_struct  *next_object_ptr;        /* 0x60: re-check this */
    u32    _0x64;
    struct object_struct  *next_object_ptr2;       /* 0x68: re-check this (child_obj) */
    u32    _0x6c;
    u32    _0x70;                  /* 0x70 */
    u16    active;                 /* 0x0000 = inactive, 0x0101 = active */
    u16    _0x76;                  /* collision flag according to YE */
    struct object_struct  *collided_obj_ptr;      /* according to YE, pointer to object collided with */
    u32    _0x7c;
    u32    _0x80;                  /* 0x80 */
    u32    _0x84;
    u32    _0x88;
    u32    obj_flags;
    u32    _0x90;                  /* 0x90 */
    u32    _0x94;
    u32    _0x98;
    u32    _0x9c;
    float  x_pos;                  /* 0xa0 */
    float  y_pos;
    float  z_pos;
    float  x_speed;  /* x increment? */
    float  y_speed;                  /* 0xb0 */
    float  z_speed;  /* z_increment? */
    float  speed;
    u32    _0xbc;
    u32    _0xc0;                  /* 0xc0 */
    u32    x_rotation;             /* 0xc4 - rotation triplet */
    u32    y_rotation;             /* 0xc8 */
    u32    z_rotation;
    u32    x_rotation2;            /* rotation copy (collision?) 0xd0 */
    u32    y_rotation2;            /* 0xd4 */
    u32    z_rotation2;
    u32    _0xd8;
    u32    _0xe0;                  /* 0xe0 */
    float  _0xe4;         /* gravity related? y_speed - 0xe4 ? */
    u32    _0xe8;
    u32    _0xec;
    u32    _0xf0;                  /* 0xf0 */
    u32    _0xf4;               /* obj type for some behaviors (ie, ice bully), for AMPS, radius of rotation */
    u32    _0xf8;
    u32    _0xfc;
    u32    _0x100;                 /* 0x100 */
    u32    _0x104;
    u32    _0x108;
    u32    _0x10c;
    u32    _0x110;                 /* 0x110 */
    u32    _0x114;
    u32    _0x118;
    u32    _0x11c;
    u32    animation_ptr;        /* 0x120 = (set by 0x27 26 behavior command) entry for animation? */
    u32    _0x124;                  /* in some behaviors, action related? */
    float  _0x128;
    float  _0x12c;
    u32    interaction;            /* 0x130 
                                      00 = Something Solid. Can't grab. Mario walks around, Can jump over.
                                      01 = Crashed when jumping at it, Used by Hoot.
                                      02 = Grabbing
                                      04 = Going through door
                                      08 = Knocks mario back and dissappears. No damage.
                                      10 = Something Solid, Can't grab, Mario walks around, Can't jump over, Seems somewhat thin..
                                      40 = Climbing 
                                   */
    u32    _0x134;
    u32    _0x138;
    u32    _0x13c;
    u32    _0x140;                 /* 0x140 */
    u32    behav_param;            /* behav param */
    u32    _0x148;
    u32    action;
    u32    _0x150;                 /* 0x150 = also reset when action changes */
    u32    timer;                  /* always incremented. When action changes, it's set to 0 */
    float  _0x158;                 
    float  distance_from_mario;
    u32    _0x160;                 /* 0x160 */
    float  _0x164_x;
    float  _0x168_y;
    float  _0x16c_z;
    float  _0x170;                 /* 0x170 */
    float  _0x174;
    u32    _0x178;
    u32    transparency;
    u32    damage_to_mario;        /* According to YE, "How many segments of damage to do to Mario for objects that cause him harm" */
    u32    health;                 /* Health (ie, for King bob-omb and whomp */
    u32    behav_param2;           /* re-check */
    u32    previous_action;        /* used to reset the 0x154 timer */
    u32    _0x190;                 /* 0x190 */
    float  collision_distance;     /*  NOTE: if collision_distance < disappear_distance then disappear_distance = collision_distance */
    u32    _0x198;
    float  drawing_distance;
    u32    _0x1a0;                 /* 0x1a0 */
    u32    _0x1a4;
    u32    _0x1a8;
    u32    _0x1ac;
    u32    _0x1b0;                 /* 0x1b0 */
    u32    _0x1b4;
    u32    _0x1b8;
    u32    _0x1bc;
    u32    _0x1c0;                 /* 0x1c0 */
    u32    _0x1c4;
    u32    _0x1c8;
    u32    script_ptr;
    u32    stack_index;            /* 0x1d0 */
    u32    stack;
    u32    _0x1d8;
    u32    _0x1dc;
    u32    _0x1e0;                 /* 0x1e0 */
    u32    _0x1e4;
    u32    _0x1e8;
    u32    _0x1ec;
    u32    _0x1f0;                 /* 0x1f0 */
    u16    _0x1f4;
    u16    _0x1f6;
    float  col_sphere_x;
    float  col_sphere_y;
    float  _0x200;                 /* 0x200 */
    float  _0x204;
    float  _0x208;
    u32    behavior_script_entry;
    u32    _0x210;                 /* 0x210 */
    u32    collide_obj_ptr;        /* pointer to another object (collision happening)?. 
                                   Can be used to detect if Mario is on top of the object by comparing
                                   value with Mario's pointer */
    u32    collision_ptr;          /* set by behavior script (0x2A command) */
    u32    _0x21c;
    u32    _0x220;                 /* 0x220 */
    u32    _0x224;
    u32    _0x228;
    u32    _0x22c;
    u32    _0x230;                 /* 0x230 */
    u32    _0x234;
    u32    _0x238;
    u32    _0x23c;
    u32    _0x240;                 /* 0x240 */
    u32    _0x244;
    u32    _0x248;
    u32    _0x24c;
    u32    _0x250;                 /* 0x250 */
    u32    _0x254;
    u32    _0x258;
    u32    behav_param_copy_ptr;
} Object;
```

Now my problem is, that I want to use it's class pointer to point to an address which contains those members.

Ex.:

```
#define M64_CURR_OBJ_PTR            0x80361160

Object **Obj = (void*)M64_CURR_OBJ_PTR;

(*Obj)->animation = 0x25; // changes animation to 0x25
```

Now, in my example it should now be somewhere at address 0x8033B1AC and change the u32 = unsigned int to 0x25. But the above part with void does not work and errors for me. Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: To begin with, you probably want an `Object*` instead of `Object**`. Then, consider using `(Object*)` instead of `(void*)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to use is a reinterpret_cast:

```
Object **Obj = reinterpret_cast<Object**>(M64_CURR_OBJ_PTR);
```

Casting to `(void*)` instead is something that you could do in C, but not in C++. In C++, you have to be more explicit. A void pointer doesn't automatically convert to another pointer type.

Comment: M64_CURR_OBJ_PTR is an external (in a game) pointer which points to an actual object. That's why the two level way.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton: Is the object stored at location 0x80361160, or does that location contain a pointer, and the object is stored somewhere else? I inferred from the question that the actual object was stored at 0x80361160.

Comment: No, 0x80361160 is a pointer which points to the current object which is being processed by the game. I'm sorry if I didn't describe it exactly enough.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton: Ok, that doesn't make sense from your question. You state that the value you are trying to change (the animation member of the object) is at address 0x8036119c, which is 0x80361160+0x3c. That would imply that the actual object is stored at 0x80361160, and not a pointer to it. What you want then is to treat 0x80361160 as a pointer, and not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Oh! That was a mistake of mine. Actually the members (of the class) are stored (starting at) 0x8033B170, so it would be 0x8033B170+0x3C = 8033B1AC. Sorry about that. Edited it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I'm still not very experienced with C++ yet (still a C guy). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do

```
    static_assert(sizeof(Object)==0x25c);
```

To verify that you compiler is packing your struct correctly. When you are mixing different sizes of integers (`uint16_t`,`uint32_t`, etc) the compiler might decide to insert padding bytes here and there.  If the `static_assert` doesn't complain, you are good to go. Otherwise, you will have to look in to the various nonstandard compiler `#pragma`s for packing structs without gaps.

Also, `typedef class object_struct { ...} Object` is old school C. Change it to the much simpler `class Object{ }`.